# Java Calculation differs

Tags: java, math, servlets, jakarta-ee, calculation

I have a simple math calculation class in JavaEE and the result is different from online java calculators. Example the website [JavaCalc](http://www.mathe-online.at/JavaCalc/jcintro.html) gives me correct result i.e. 0.0009. However, for me in my java program, the result becomes 9.xxx.

Math Equation used on above URL:

```
(0.5) * ((0.85724038)-(0.779))/((40.32173718)-(0.779))
```

Java equation:

```
Total_Score = (0.5) * ((T) - (N)) / ((ME) - (N));
```

Where:
T = 0.85724038

N = 0.779

M = 40.32173718

I am quite confused as for why is the answer different when both equations are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to actually display the number in non-scientific notation, you can use `format`:

```
String.format("%.Xf", yourNumHere);
```

Where `X` is the number of decimal places to show to. If you wanted it to show to 9 decimal places, the format string would be `"%.9f"`.

Comment: syntax `Double.parseDouble(String.format("%.9f", value));` gives `9.89314E-4`.

Comment: @Nix That likely means that you had already converted it to a string prior to giving it to `format`. I just tested it, and it works fine (in Clojure, granted, but it should be identical).

Comment: Actually giving it a string causes an error. I don't know what you did. `(String/format "%.9f" (to-array [(* 0.000125 0.00069)]))` yields `"0.000000086"`.

Answer (score 2):

The result is the same in calculations, but it is displayed differently. My output is
9.893141646194965E-4
which means 0.0009xxxxx. The "E" stands for scientific notation, and E-4 means move the decimal point four to the left (thus becoming 0.0009xxxxxxxxxx). It can also be written as 9.893141646194965 * 10^-4. They are the same value, but I guess that `System.out.println()` converts numbers to scientific notation if that is easier to read. Java interprets these values as the same.

Comment: @Nix They're the same. It's just a visual difference.

Comment: @Carcigenicate correct but the requirement is to show only in number and not in scientific notation. so I want to show that result in 0.00 format rather than E-4

Comment: @Nix Then this will do: `System.out.printf("%f\n", value);` and replace value with your equasion.

Comment: @PieterMantel syntax `Double.parseDouble(String.format("%f", value));` gives `9.89E-4`.

Comment: @Nix Wait, you can't parse it again, that defeats the purpose of formatting it in the first place. You cannot have an actual double in the format you're looking for. `format` it before you print it, but keep it as a double until then. It's the same thing.